# iframe gets displaced on iOS when dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iframe

I have an iframe on my website that is populated when you click the `Make an Appointment` button. The iframe contains a contact form with several input fields.

Everything works fine, but for some reason on iOS (iPad and iPhone 5/6 - I tested Safari and Chrome) the form is draggable beyond its container's width and height. It should only be scrollable in the y-axis; like it is on Android devices. See screenshot below.

I've looked at numerous posts on S/O, but have yet to find any Q/A that pertains to this particular nuance of iOS devices/browsers.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id='button'><button id='contact'>MAKE AN APPOINTMENT</button></div>
    <div id="block"></div>
       <div id="iframecontainer">
           <a id='close' href='#'>X</a>
          <div id="loader"></div>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#block').fadeIn();
    $('#iframecontainer').fadeIn();
    $('#header-wrapper').css("visibility", "hidden");
     var width = $(window).width();
    $('#iframecontainer iframe').attr('src', 'http://a-link-to-my-iframe.html');
    if (width > 850) {
        $('#iframecontainer').css('width', '790px');
        $('#iframecontainer').css('margin-left', '-395px');
    }
    else {
        $('#iframecontainer').css('width', '310px');
        $('#iframecontainer').css('margin-left', '-155px');
    }
    $('#iframecontainer iframe').load(function() {
         $('#loader').fadeOut(function() {
            $('iframe').fadeIn();
         });
     });
   });
```

And, the CSS:

```
#contact {
  color: #c2c2c2;
  background: #151515;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  padding: 13px 26px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: inherit;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#iframecontainer {
  width:75%; 
  height: auto; 
  display: none; 
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:600px;
  top: 10%; 
  background:#FFF; 
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222;
  z-index: 999999;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -395px;
}
#iframecontainer iframe { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 600px; 
  position: absolute; 
  border: none; 
}
#loader { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 250px; 
  margin:auto;
}
#block {
  background: #000; 
  opacity:0.6;  
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  display:none;
}​
```

And here is a screen shot of what I am referring to:

[image: Dragging the iframe down-right]

Is there a specific way to disable this on iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `scrolling="no"` on the iframe and change some iframe CSS like,

```
#iframecontainer iframe { 
  width: 1px;/* Make it a very small for your viewport */
  min-width:100%;/* Overwrite width. Let it decides the actual width of iframe */
  height: 600px; 
  position: absolute; 
  border: none; 
}
```

Comment: scrolling="no" was depricated in HTML5 I believe. I'll try the CSS suggestions.

Comment: Update: I tried the solution above, but that did not work. I need to be able to scroll the form in the y-axis. I am looking to disable this "rubber band" like feature when scrolling.